# How to override ContentControlThemeFontFamily

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

is it possible to set a custom font for ContentControlThemeFontFamily in WinRt Applications in the standardstyles.xaml?

do you have any example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a resource dictionary of your own and override the themes.

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
         <FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">Times new roman</FontFamily>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesn't work with custom fonts for me.
eg: <FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Fonts/3173.ttf#Digital Readout Thick Upright</FontFamily>

Comment: Worked for me when adding in StandardStyles.xaml  which was a ResourceDictionary / MergedDictionaries  `<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Assets/gilsbrg.ttf#Gill Sans Infant MT</FontFamily>`   Font set to Build Action - Content | Do Not Copy

Comment: How do you override the font size for a given control?  For example, I want all my Content controls to have a font size of 14.