# Set default font in UWP application

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing UWP application and I need to change font for all components in application.

In WPF applications this was easy to do by setting font family to `Window` type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="MV Boli" />
</Style>
```

I have tried similar strategy in UWP and I have used `Page` type, but this is not working:

```
<Style TargetType="Page">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="MV Boli" />
</Style>
```

I can change font for specific type of elements, but not for all controls.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to override the ContentControlThemeFontFamily resource in the default theme dictionary? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227669/how-to-override-contentcontrolthemefontfamily

Comment: No I didn't I will try that. Thank you